# Why it is considered as a benefit not to share the access token with the resource owner?

Tags: oauth-2.0

According to the IETF's OAuth 2.0 document [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1), it is implied that it is a good practice not to expose the token issued by the authorization server to the resource owner:

> The authorization code provides a few important security benefits,
> such as the ability to authenticate the client, as well as the
> transmission of the access token directly to the client without
> passing it through the resource owner's user-agent and potentially
> exposing it to others, **including the resource owner**.

Do you know any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

It highlights that access tokens are credentials that must be kept confidential and available only to:

- the authorization server that issued them
- the resource server for which the credentials are valid
- **the client application application to which they were issued**

Not even the resource owner needs access to these credentials; the most important part of the authorization code is of course reducing the risk of exposure to others, however, having an explicit note to mention the resource owner makes it clear that the target recipient of an access token is the client application.

Comment: Maybe it is meant to emphasise that the exposure of the toke should be kept minimal, but, yet I don't find any reason why the end user should not have access to the token.

Comment: Like I said the access token is intended for the client application, exposing it with to the resource owner just needlessly increases the possibility of leaks. For example, the end-user can bookmark it, share a link containing access tokens, etc.